# Check for Cookie, if it does not exist run script

Tags: jquery, cookies, modal-dialog

I'm struggling with the use of Cookies on a html page. I would like to have a script check to see if a user has a cookie, if not call this script to open a model window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#myModal").reveal();
});
</script
```

The window contains "Yes" and "No" buttons, if you user selects "Yes" it will save a cookie so the modal doesn't open on future visits to that page, if the user selects "No" it will simply direct them to another page.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use the jQuery cookie library for ease of use. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

2) Check if cookie exists and handle accordingly

```
if ($j.cookie("NameOfYourCookie") == null) {
//Do stuff if cookie doesn't exist like set a cookie with a value of 1
$j.cookie("NameOfYourCookie", 1, {expires: 10, path:'/'});
}

else {
//They have a cookie so do something
alert ('You have a cookie with name NameOfYourCookie');
}
```

*** EDIT ***

Thought I might edit my answer to be more appropriate to your question.

```
        <button class="yes">YES</button>
        <button class="no">No</button>

     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
//Show modal on page load           
$j("#myModal").show();  



$j('.yes').click(function(){
        $j("#myModal").hide();
        $j.cookie("YesButtonCookie", 1, {expires: 10, path:'/'});
        alert ('You have clicked yes, a cookie has been dropped');

  });


        if ($j.cookie("YesButtonCookie") == 1){
            // Don't show the div
            $j("#myModal").hide(); 
            alert ('Cookie found, you cant see myModal');
        }


        if ($j.cookie("YesButtonCookie") == null){
                    // Cookie Not Found
                    alert ('Cookie Not found, you can see myModal');
                    $j("#myModal").show();
        }




    $j('.clearcookie').click(function(){
        $j.cookie("YesButtonCookie", null);
        alert('Cookie Cleared');
    });


});
```

[JSFIDDLE TO TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/S8NTg/2/)

Comment: WOW that's what I call a detailed answer!! I'm having a little bit of problem though, when I visit the JSFiddle page in Firefox it alerts me that the cookie was found, so I tried the clear button and refreshed the page but it still found the cookie. So I tried in IE and it doesn't find the cookie (after clicking the "yes" button) then refreshing. Am I missing something or is this not quite working properly yet?

Comment: I might not have cleared the cookie properly in the fiddle or not called it correctly. The basic outline is there though. Use the jQuery cookie plug in, then set the cookie with $j.cookie("CookieName", IntValue, {expires: IntDaysToExpire, path:'/'}); to check if the cookie is loaded check for the value you assigned it. In my example I set the value to 1 so you would check if the cookie has a value of one if($j.cookie("CookieName") == 1) {//do stuff}. Once you are able to set / read the cookies then everything you want to do falls in a combination of if statements. Hope it helps.